# Django 2.2 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django 2.2 in a project. I am rolling an extra lightweight app that allows users to modify the raw HTML used in a template.

This is a cut down example of the function I have written to do that:

```
def show_page(request):
    from django.template import Context, Template
    template = Template("<h3>My name is {{ my_name }}.</h3>")

    context = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
    return template.render(context)  # <- Django barfs at this line
```

I get the exception shown in the title:

> AttributeError at /show-page 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'

How do I resolve this error, so I can display the page correctly?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `show_page` is a Django view, you should be returning a `Response` object, not the template string.

Change your view by adding:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Answer (score 2):

From Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest)

> Each view you write is responsible for instantiating, populating, and returning an **`HttpResponse`**.

Currently you are returning a `django.utils.safestring.SafeString` which is just a subclassed string

> A str subclass that has been specifically marked as "safe" for HTML
> output
> purposes.

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```